# Fail to trigger Hummingbird Treeview sub-node checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I am using **[hummingbird-treeview.js](https://hummingbird-dev.000webhostapp.com/hummingbird_v1.php)** plugin with font-awesome v4.7.0.
I want to render a hierarchical tree structure with the checkbox.
When I try to trigger the root node of the checkbox, the correspond sub-node checkbox can't trigger immediately.

**Example illustration** (click root node checkbox can auto trigger sub-node checkbox).

[image]

**How it currently looks**:

[image]

My current code is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="treeview_container" class="hummingbird-treeview" style="height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <ul id="treeview" class="hummingbird-base"></ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//initializing
$("#treeview").hummingbird();

for(var i = 0; i < depth; i++) {

    var strContent = "<li><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> <label><input id='xnode-0' data-id='custom-0' type='checkbox' /> " + "node-"+ i;
    strContent += "</label><ul><li><label><input class='hummingbird-end-node' id='xnode-0-1' data-id='custom-0-1' type='checkbox'/> " + "node-"+ i + "-1";
    strContent += "</label></li></ul></li>";

    $("#treeview").append(strContent);
}
```

Comment: Initialize after the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, initializing after adding content should work.
However, the newest version of the hummingbird-treeview.js now provides a method for adding content called "addNode": https://github.com/hummingbird-dev/hummingbird-treeview